# ReactionCollector in Discord.js user.send() is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I created a ReactionCollector for my Discord Bot, but if I want to send a message to the user the error user.send() is not a function comes up. My Discord.js version is v11.

```
    const filter = (reaction, user) => {
        return validEmojis.includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id !== bot.user.id;
};
    const collector = message.createReactionCollector(filter)

    collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
        if (reaction.emoji.name === "") {
            user.send("hello")
        }       
    });
```

Log output of the reaction parameter in the ReactionCollector:

```
<ref *1> MessageReaction {
  message: Message {
  me: true,
  count: 2,
  users: Collection(1) [Map] {
    '342000434514493440' => User {
      id: '342000434514493440',
      username: 'TFS_NerzDesmony',
      discriminator: '7832',
      avatar: 'b05491a41564a2f32811b55d4ea44103',
      bot: false,
      lastMessageID: null,
      lastMessage: null
    }
  },
  _emoji: ReactionEmoji {
    reaction: [Circular *1],
    name: '',
    id: null,
    animated: false
  }
}
```

Hope anyone can help me solve this problem

Comment: Discord.js version?

Comment: the discord.js version is v11

Comment: Discord.js v11 use two parameters, element and collector, not reaction and user.

Comment: Is there any other way to send an message to the user?

Comment: Log reaction and add a screenshot of its content in your question

Comment: v11 is broken. Use v13 instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `user.send("hello")` by `reaction.users.first().send("hello")` according to [MessageReaction](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v11/class/MessageReaction) since you are using Discord.js v11.